# Hierarchical data for comment system

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to add a comment system that uses hierarchical design. Here's a sample from my database that keeps track of posts/replies (note that more rows are added as more people reply):

```
post_id | parent_id
   1          1
   2          1
   3          1
   4          2
   5          3
   6          2
   7          4
```

I've done some research about different methods to output and manipulate the data to get what you need, but I'm not sure which method would be best for a comment system and how I would do it.

I know that adjacency lists wouldn't work because it can't handle deep trees.

Please help.

Comment: You don't really need a *deep* tree. More than dozen nested levels would be unusable

Comment: @YourCommonSense That really depends on the number of replies.

Comment: Indeed. 20 nested replies would be unreadable

Comment: How come they would be unreadable?

Comment: Please, try to picture yourself a rendered result of your code. A developer should always have such a picture in mind. Try to nest 20 replies on one page and see the result.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. Are you saying that it would become slow?

Comment: I am talking of *picture*. Do you realize how 20 nested comments would look? What space would be left for the last one? Do you realize what nested comments is? Did you ever try to visualize this Hierarchical comment system you are trying to make?

Answer (score -1):

Judging by nowadays trends, AL is quite acceptable solution. All modern sites tend to dump all the comments on one page - means no sophisticated SQL logic ever required but just simple query for all the comments belongs to single article. And one loop to store them in array.

If you want no loops but get all the comments in one query already sorted, then Materialized Path would be handy. For the implementation you can find plenty of examples, I am sure.

Comment: With materialized paths, what if the path were extremely long (for example: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...1000`)? How slow would it become?

Comment: Again you take it wrong. 1000 nested levels definitely impossible. While 10-20 is quite bearable number. Note that 1,2,3 won't work I believe. 000100020003 it have to be.

Comment: or better convert the numbers to base36 to shorten them even more

Comment: This is all assuming that there won't be thousands of replies to a post, which I think is bad to assume. Are there any other ways (besides hierarchies) to do what I need to do?

Comment: Well, this path I provided assuming 10 000 replies which is pretty big number. Especially taking into account that you have no posts, nor comments, nor users to comment yet